# Generating html table from SQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql, html-table

I'm enthusiast so sorry for the lousy code.. anyway I have a form where I can select values that range from 5 to 50, and I compare these values with $pacote. For every different value found on database for $pacote, I want to create a new row in my html table ("Pacote xx horas")", and display this value in the columns where it's supposed to appear. In my example image I set values 10 ( for 3 specific html table columns -> Aeroboero AB-115, Cessna 172K and Cessna 172SP) and 25 ( for 1 column). This is what I got, and what I want to get. I tried many different things but ran out of ideas!

Example image: [image]

```
... <more code above> ...

for ($pacote = 5; $pacote <= 50; $pacote = $pacote + 5) {

    $priceQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM precos_hora WHERE Pacote1_horas = $pacote");
    $priceQuery1 = mysql_query("SELECT Pacote1_horas FROM precos_hora");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($priceQuery)) {

        if (is_null($priceQuery)) {
            echo "";
        } else {    
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>Pacote ".$pacote." horas</td>";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($priceQuery1)) {

                if ($priceQuery = $pacote) {

                    echo "<td>R$ ".$row['Pacote1_horas']."</td>";
                } else {
                    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";

                } // CLOSE ELSE //
            } // CLOSE WHILE //

            echo "</tr>";

        } // CLOSE ELSE //
    } // CLOSE WHILE //
} // CLOSE FOR //
```

Comment: The "(is_null($priceQuery)) {"  test is used to generate a new <tr> for every single value found in the query (which is the first column in the html table - > "Pacote xx horas").  Concerning your suggestion on "if ($row['Pacote1_horas'] == $pacote) {", I already tried that since it is indeed the correct test to do,  but I didn't get what I expected. I'll work more on that anyway. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue is this line `if ($priceQuery = $pacote) {`   This assigns the value of `$pacote` to `$priceQuery` which will always evaluate to true, so the 'else' part will never run.

You need a double-equals to evaluate 2 variables.. ..and you are evaluating an incrementing number `$pacote` with the results of a query `$priceQuery`.  This where your issue is.  At a guess, I would say that you need something like:

```
if ($row['Pacote1_horas'] == $pacote) {
```

Also, you probably dont need the `if (is_null($priceQuery)) {` test..  Your while loop loops through each returned record from the query, so not much point checking that is is NTLL, 'cause it wont ever be.

Lastly, you should think about changing your `mysql_*` functions to `mysqli_*`, as the former methos is now deprecated, and vulnerable to SQL injection.